# Could Frida SocketListener accept more than one connect?

Tags: sockets, frida

I want to using Frida Socket to create a tcp server, and accept multiple clients.

JS code:

```
function failure(err)
{
    console.error(err.message);
}
function accepted(connection)
{
    console.warn('accepted');
    connection.close();
}
function listened(listener)
{
    console.warn('listened');
    listener.accept()
        .then(accepted)
        .catch(failure);
}
function interaction()
{
    Socket.listen({"family": 'unix', 'host': '127.0.0.1', 'port': 6658})
        .then(listened)
        .catch(failure);
}
interaction();
```

Test using Python:

```py
import socket

address = "127.0.0.1"
port = 6658

def test_frida_socket():
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    s.connect((address, port))
    s.close()

test_frida_socket()
```

I ran the python code 4 times, but 'accepted' was printed only the first time.

Comment: Surprised it was ever printed at all. 127.0.0.1 is an IPv4 address, not a UNIX address.